# creating an array from variables

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I have an array as follows

```
Object[][] data = {assd, eventy,assFT}
```

assd, eventy and assFT are variables and hold different values, all three variables hold many values. The variables are fed through from a loop.

How can i create the array so it creates an array like this

```
Object[][] data = {{assd, eventy,assFT},
                   {assd, eventy,assFT}}
```

which would represent say for example

```
Object[][] data = {{hello, goodbye,salut},
                   {hallo, ,gutentag,aurevoir}}
```

Currently what i am getting by having

```
Object[][] data = {assd, eventy,assFT}
```

is

```
Object[][] data = {hello hallo, goodbye gutentag,salut aurevoir}
```

ie i am getting each variable adding to the same index of the first row of the array.

Comment: Show the code which initializing the three variables and _How can i create the array so it creates an array_ means you are trying to create the array `data` ?

Comment: Are you asking how you initialize a 2d array, or how you programmatically set values into elements in a 2d array?

Comment: You need to show the exact code that you're trying because your question does not make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a method that parses the `assd`, `eventy`, and `assFT` arrays and then reinsert them into a new two dimensional array in the correct format like so:

```
Object[][] combineArrays(Object[] assd, Object[] eventy, Object[] assFT)
{
    Object[][] outputArray = new Object[3][];
    outputArray[0] = new Object[assd.length];
    outputArray[1] = new Object[eventy.length];
    outputArray[2] = new Object[assFT.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < assd.length; i++)
    {
        outputArray[i][0] = assd[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < assd.length; i++)
    {
        outputArray[i][1] = eventy[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < assd.length; i++)
    {
        outputArray[i][2] = assFT[i];
    }

    return outputArray;
}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/aTz2bS) for proof that this works. I did use `int`s though instead of `Object`s though to make it easy on Ideone.

Sorry it took so long to answer your question. I saw it a while ago and didn't have time to type up my answer before leaving my computer.

Comment: This is much more like what i am looking for, let me try and apply it to my scenario, this is exactly the logic im looking for. Il get back to you on how i go and give you the rating once i have applied it. many thanks. I searched the web for the proof link you sent, with no luck, thanks for this link its very very useful :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help